# Finding coefficients of vector with positive y axis when angle is given

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

***Question:*** If the vector $x\,\hat i + y\,\hat j -2\,\hat k $  makes an angle of $\pi-\operatorname{arccos}(\frac{1}{3})$ with the positive $y$-axis, the find the value of $x$ and $y$.

---

What I have done so far:

I've tried using the scalar product for finding the angle;
$a\cdot b = |a||b| \operatorname{cos}(\theta).$

I've tried substituting in $y$ and $x$ but I ended up nowhere.

Comment: At least 3 quantities are required for a vector to be uniquely determined. Since the Question only provides 2 quantities, the vector can't be uniquely determined.
Therefore one can only find the relation between $x,y$ and not the exact values of $x,y$

Comment: Please write question in proper form ,i am confused in 2k is it component of vector or constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt looks good: take $\vec{a} = (x,y,-2)$ and $\vec{b} = (0,1,0).$ You know that the angle between them will be $\theta = \pi - \arccos(\frac{1}{3})$, so $\cos (\theta) = \cos\pi\cdot\cos(\arccos(\frac{1}{3})) -\sin\pi\cdot\sin(\arccos(\frac{1}{3}))= -\frac{1}{3}.$ Since $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = x\cdot0 + y\cdot 1+ -2\cdot0 = y, \, |\vec{b}| = 1$, you have that $$ y =-\frac{|\vec{a}|}{3} = -\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+4} \implies 8y^2 - x^2 = 4 .$$

Note that this is the equation of a hyperbola. So any solution $(x,y)$ of the above equation with $y < 0$ solves the problem. Try to visualize this geometrically!

Comment: Just to be clear: the geometric visualization of the hyperbola part is using the conic definition of a hyperbola and the constraints of the problem in terms of projection of the vector onto the $y$-axis.

Comment: Hey Lucas Henrique, thanks so much for your explanation. I finally understand how to do it. Your way was very short and concise unlike the other ways i've tried haha. Anyways, thank you again <3

Comment: OP: if you’re satisfied with the answer and you think it’s the correct answer to your problem, please consider upvoting and tagging it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Lucas. Im new to maths stackexchange haha. Not used to the formatting yet. Anyways, thank you.